# How to make Navbar collapse upon selection?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, navbar, expand

I've created a Meteor project which uses Twitter Bootstrap for the layout.  I have a Nav-bar which is laid out like this:  [Bootstrap Components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

My problem is, on mobile the nav-bar goes into the collapsible mode (which is fine), but when I click the links which route to other templates (using iton:router package).  The collapsible menu stays expanded.  Is there a way to get it closed upon selecting an item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add:

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click();
```

To each route you want (in the router.js file). Or the better option is to define it as a function which you call at each route.

```
Router.route('/somewhere', function(){
    $(".navbar-toggle").click();
    this.render("navbar", {to:"navbar"});
    this.render("something", {to:"main"});
});
```

Edit:

Using `$('.navbar-toggle').click();` once off instead of applying it to each route, you can do that following in the router.js file:

```
Router.configure({
  onAfterAction: function() {
    if($('#navbar-collapse').hasClass('in')) {
      $('.navbar-toggle').click();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm editing your answer to make an even more efficeint way of doing things, I just need that $(".navbar-toggle").click function :)